# Grease Pencil objects

Tags: grease-pencil

playing around with the greasepencil stuff I am wondering if there is already the possibility to:

- transform (move,scale,rotate) grease pencils along with their parent objects?
- hide the parent object but keep the greasepencil visible?

E.g. create a null, paint a grease pencil tree, duplicate the null and move it around to create a forest.
Thx

Comment: For everyone in the future. This should be possible in Blender 2.8: https://code.blender.org/2017/06/grease-pencil-sneak-peek/

Comment: Now available !  Roads? Where we're going, we don't need roads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not currently possible. There is some development happening with the grease pencil now so this may change in future versions.

After drawing a grease pencil stroke you can convert it to a curve object. This can be found in the grease pencil toolbar options.

[image]

This will convert the one active grease pencil layer to a curve object. The drawback is you loose any of the new fill settings and you need to bevel the curve and give it a material. Once you have the curve you can parent and duplicate as you want.

For the example you give I would draw a tree on an image and use the image as a texture on a plane.

Comment: Alright...maybe it's time to write my first addon if I ever find the time...

Comment: Hi guys, is it still impossible to do ?

Comment: I haven't seen any demos of new additions that suggest this is going to change, nothing was added in 2.77