# GreasePencil: can't copy datablock

Tags: python, grease-pencil

Trying to create [a GreasePencil addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24226/grease-pencil-objects/24258#24258) I already fail at the first task. It seems the GreasePencil [doesn't inherit the copy() function from ID](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_5/bpy.types.ID.html#bpy.types.ID.copy).
Where and how could I add this (as this is pretty crucial for what I try to do)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, GD copy() is not implemented.

No way to know that from python afaik, you have to look at the C code (`source/blender/blenkernel/intern/library.c`, `id_copy()` function, around line 300).

Comment: thx... I will put my project on hold then, as this exceeds my time limit unfortunately :/